# How do I open an S3 file in a new tab, renaming it from the stored name?

Tags: c#, angular, amazon-s3

We store files as a GUID in an S3 bucket.  If someone wants to download a file (through the angular front end), I can rename it to its original name (stored in the database).  When opening to a new tab however, I cannot seem to get it to rename from its GUID store name.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can point me in the right direction.

I tried using "response content type", but perhaps I did that incorrectly (deleted now).

Comment: Your angular app does not talk to your own server application that then maybe talks to S3? It talks directly with S3?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.